# Finding the most common letter in a string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find the most common letter in a string.

Here is the hint I was given but cannot figure it out

> 1. initialize an integer array of size 26 to all zeros (suppose this array is letterCount)
> 2. convert the input string to all lowercase (suppose the string is encodedString)
> 3. using a for loop step through the string character by character. Using isalpha check to see if the character is an alphabetic character. If it is, then increment your array as follows: `letterCount[encodedstring[x]-97]++`

EDIT: My Code

```
int computeShift(std::string fileContent)
{
    int letterCount[26] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(fileContent[i]))
        {
            letterCount[fileContent[i]-97]++;
        }
    }
    return 3; //Temporary
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That's not a hint. That's the answer.

Comment: I've tried what I was given but keep getting Segmentation Error

Comment: Please provide the exact code that you tried, or else we can't tell what you may have done wrong in implementing it.

Comment: Ok, I've added my code via PasteBin

Comment: @WesB You are not doing step #2 - convert the input string to lowercase before you then iterate the characters in it

Comment: @RemyLebeau the parameter passed is already lowercase

Comment: @WesB  The hint implies that it won't always be lower case which is why step two exists.  So except for that the code looks like it does what the hint says.  What doesn't work about it?

Comment: SO doesn't exist to solve your homework. What have you already tried to solve this problem? Post your code

Comment: Please use the debugger or additional console output to determine **what input** is causing your segmentation error. Also helpful would be **what line** of your code is causing it. Your code does not cause segmentation error when I try running it with basic lowercase input.

Comment: Life would make more sense if your replaced `97` with `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing step #2:

> 2. **convert the input string to all lowercase** (suppose the string is encodedString)

This is important so that both `'a'` and `'A'` can be mapped to array index 0, `'b'` and `'B'` can both be mapped to index 1, and so on.

So you can either:

- transform the input string to all lowercase before you loop through it:

```cpp
#include <cctype>

std::string str_tolower(std::string s) {
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), 
        [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); }
    );
    return s;
}

int computeShift(std::string fileContent)
{
    int letterCount[26] = { 0 };
    std::string fileContentLowerCase = str_tolower(fileContent);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileContentLowerCase.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (std::isalpha(fileContentLowerCase[i]))
        {
            letterCount[fileContentLowerCase[i]-'a']++;
        }
    }

    return 3; //Temporary
}
```

- leave the input string as-is and use `isupper()` and `islower()` instead:

```cpp
#include <cctype>

int computeShift(std::string fileContent)
{
    int letterCount[26] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (std::isalpha(fileContent[i]))
        {
            int index = std::isupper(fileContent[i])
                ? (fileContent[i]-'A')
                : (fileContent[i]-'a');
            letterCount[index]++;
        }
    }

    return 3; //Temporary
}
```